# db2 sql select statement and aggregate functions

Tags: sql, select, db2, subquery

Hi everyone I have these three tables.

```
> PS: Size(PK), Price
> P: PID(PK),PName 
> S: size(PK,FK1),PID(PK,FK2),quantity
```

i wanted to select the PName and the  quantity of each size of that PName has been sold.
Basically i'm expecting this result:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------
> PName | SSize_Qty | RSize_Qty| LSize_qty |
> ----------------------------------------------------------
> XYZ   | 34            | 15             | 234           |
> ----------------------------------------------------------
> ABC   | 24            | 23             | 87            |
> ----------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried the following code to get the first 2 columns:

```
select PName,
(select count(quantity) from Product p, sales s
where P_size = 'P'
and p.pid = s.pid) as Q_P_Size
from sales s, Product p, pricesize ps
where s.PID = p.PID
and ps.P_size = s.P_size
group by PName
```

but it gives me the whole total quantity of all the Products, which is not what i want
I hope someone can help me with this

Comment: Please format the question correctly before posting.

Comment: What are the definitions of `SSize_Qty`, `RSize_Qty` and `LSize_qty`? The names imply that each one is a "quantity" of something, but nothing tells us what "something" is. How do you know when some value should be included in any of those three results? You show "expected result"; but you don't show any input data, so we have no idea how input relates to your result. Please edit your question to clarify the situation.

Comment: @user2338816 basically they represent the quantity sold of that size.. for example product ABC(let's assume it's a Pizza); our store has sold 34 small pizza, 23 regular pizza, and 87 large pizza. the code i put actually return the whole total quantity of the product sold but i want the detailed when when it gives me the quantity sold of each size. I wish you can help me with that.

Comment: So `Q_P_Size` is the `sum()` for `P_size = 'P'` and is reported as `SSize_Qty`? And the other two result columns would be for two other `P_size` values? If so, three CASE() functions can be constructed fairly easily.

Comment: The design seems odd. `sales` seems to be an associative table that allows `s.size` to have many `s.PID` values and `s.PID` to have many `s.size` values. Any query either must account for that or risk failing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you start by counting the quantity per name and size:

```
select p.pname, ps.size, count(s.quantity) as qty
from Product p
join Sales s
    on s.PID = p.PID
join pricesize ps
    on ps.size = s.size
group by p.pname, ps.size
```

This will give you something like:

```
---------------------------------
> PName | Size | Qty| LSize_qty |
> -------------------------------
> XYZ   | P    | 34             |
---------------------------------
> XYZ   | R    | 23             | 
> -------------------------------
> XYZ   | L    | 87             |
---------------------------------
> ABC   | P    | 24             |
---------------------------------
[...]
```

Now you can transpose this using case and aggregate functions:

```
select pname
     , max( case when size = 'P' then qty end ) as SSize_Qty
     , max( case when size = 'R' then qty end ) as RSize_Qty
     , max( case when size = 'L' then qty end ) as LSize_Qty
from (
    select p.pname, ps.size, count(s.quantity) as qty
    from Product p
    join Sales s
        on s.PID = p.PID
    join pricesize ps
        on ps.size = s.size
    group by p.pname, ps.size
)
group by pname;
```

but since this is "presentation" I suggest you do this in the application. All untested so there is likely some typing error.